# Class member has value in Watch but throw null reference exception when step over

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, tfs-workitem

```
 public class TfsProject : ITfsProject
    {
    private Project m_TfsProject;
    private TswaClientHyperlinkService m_TfsHyperlinkService;

public TfsProject(Project p) //class constructor
        {
            m_TfsProject = p;
            m_TfsHyperlinkService = (TswaClientHyperlinkService)(p.Store.TeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(TswaClientHyperlinkService)));

        }

...........................

public WorkItemDescriptor GetDescriptor(int id)
        {
            WorkItemDescriptor workitem= new WorkItemDescriptor();
            workitem.WorkItemId = id;
            workitem.HyperlinkUri = m_TfsHyperlinkService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(id).AbsoluteUri;
            return workitem;
        }

    ..................
}
```

in Watch and QuickWatch  **m_TfsHyperlinkService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(id).AbsoluteUri** has value, but when i try to assign/return this value throws null reference exception.

```
var a = m_TfsHyperlinkService; //has value !=null
var b= a.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(id) //has value !=null in Watch but throw null reference exception when step over
```

Comment: Is this application is a multi-threaded?  May be, value, that m_TfsHyperlinkService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(id) returns, changes from call to call.

Comment: no, is not multi-threaded. i've call GetDescriptor in constructor, right after m_TfsHyperlinkService = ... but same result.

Comment: Problem solved after update Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll to 14.00 from 12.00